# Current draw in a battery contactor

Tags: batteries, relay

In a battery continuous contactor used as a master switch, what limits the current draw through the coil once the contact is shut?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Can you add a schematic? We have an awesome on-site schematic editor, which you can start-up with Ctrl-M.

Comment: will add later in the day, on my ipad right now, thanks for the info though

Comment: Or a model and part number, that can help too.

Comment: schematic shown here: [link](http://davidson-der.com/Genavelectsys.asp)

Answer (score 2):

The DC resistance of the coil itself limits the current through it.

Comment: that's what i figured thanks, was curious also since usually it is a much thinner gauge wire in a system with high current loads